# Grid with distributed items

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to build a grid in which the items are equidistant from each other in a row. 
Is it possible to achieve this layout with css without running in this issue in the last row ?

[image: Distribution in last line]

I made a little pen to demo the problem 
http://codepen.io/Koopa/pen/RWBdxX

Haml

```
<input type="range" id="weight" min="36" value="52" max="72" step="2">
<div id="container">
- 20.times do
  %div.item
    %div
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  text-align: justify;
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 240px;
}
#container div.item {
  width: 36px;
  height: 64px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  div{
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
#container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    var width = $(this).val();
    $('#container div').width(width)
    $('#container div').height(width * 16/9)
});
```

Thanks

Kind regards

Koopa

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you are after (although I can guess) and also how flexible you need this to be. Should it work for a specific number of elements per row. Are there actual "row" containers? What restrictions are in place...etc. Flexbox can do most of this but it's not a total solution.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have given more explanation... Well I want a grid with a fixed width in which the elements are resizable. When the elements become too big to fit into one row they float into the next one. This is why I need to distribute the items equally over the width of the grid container, because I want them to be centered. However with the method I chose I'm unable to avoid the gap when there are 2 items in the last row. In the last row the elements should be floated to the left

Comment: Yeah...AFAIK you can't do that with a wrapping row....unfortunately.